# How to prioritise a busy queue so low priority items get processed too?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, sorting, queue, scheduling

We have implement a basic queue of jobs using a mysql table where some items in it have a lower priority than the rest. Since the queue is continuously filled with high priority items then low priority items sometimes never get processed.

In our implementation we insert the item along with its priority into the table and to get the next item from the queue, we query the table like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `queue` ORDER BY `priority` DESC, `created_at` ASC
```

How should we model the queue so lower priority items still get processed in a timely manner?

### EDIT

The queue usually contains over 25,000 items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can weight the priority by the time in the queue. That way, priority increases the longer the task has been outstanding, and eventually these tasks should move towards the top of the list.

It looks like you already have data regarding when the task was logged ("created_at"), so I think you have everything needed:

```
SELECT * FROM queue ORDER BY priority*( now() - created_at ) DESC
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'm going to try it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Or `priority + (now() - created_at)` (which will obviously give a completely different answer), or really any function of the two that increase as either increases. One will have to play around to find the desired behaviour (or mathematically determine the function).

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to do this is to increase the priority of every item in the queue immediately after picking one. This way the older, low priority items will at one point accumulate enough priority to overtake any new high priority items.

Something like a cycle of

```
SELECT * FROM `queue` ORDER BY `priority` DESC, `created_at` ASC LIMIT 1;
-- read selected queue item
DELETE FROM `queue`WHERE <primary key>=<primary key of selected element>;
UPDATE `queue` SET `priority`=`priority`+1;
```

should be good enough

Answer (score 1):

Two answers have been posted, one using dynamically calculated time difference and another involving update of the whole database. A third option which does not require either of those is to adjust the priority values themselves upon inserting a new item. For instance, when inserting a item with priority P set the 'priority' column to P and set another column 'priority_adjusted' to P - X, where X is an integer that is being increased by one, say, every second or every minute. Then the query

```
SELECT * FROM `queue` ORDER BY `priority_adjusted` DESC;
```

returns the items in order of processing, and the column 'priority' contains the original priority. This should be fast because it does not require dynamic calculation of anything and database updates are not needed.

The system handling the database must just do:

```
every <time interval>:
   X = X + 1
```

and when inserting set `priority_adjusted` to `priority` minus X.

If your priority values are, say, between 1..100, then after 100 intervals (X increased 100 times) all the lowest priority items from time 0 will be processed before any items inserted at time 100.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, used sometimes in thread scheduling, is to add a virtual item to each priority level.

At each priority level the items are selected in the order of their arrival. The virtual item at the current priority level, when selected, would trigger selection of an item from lower priority, and get re-inserted in the back of the queue.

This ensures that lower priority item would neither get neglected nor get picked up faster than a higher priority item.

Comment: I like your idea, but I am not sure it can be implemented easily using simple SQL?